# What is the "Minion's mistake" music in "Megamind"?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

There is a [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0RyXf2Xb60) where Megamind is standing in front of everyone and Minion has a music player that is playing ACDC's *Highway to Hell* and when Megamind orders him to stop, he accidentally plays something like a love song (La la la...).

I'm asking if you know what that sing is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Loving you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MCpNMB9RBA) from Minnie Riperton.

You can compare with the [megamind-scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0RyXf2Xb60) (at 0:50)